# Python3 USB (Linux) - work with keyboard with 2 interfaces and 3 endpoints

Tags: python, linux-kernel, usb

I have a **Logitech G510** keyboard and I'm using Xubuntu 23.04.
The output of the command `lsusb -s 003:079 -v` is:

```
Bus 003 Device 079: ID 046d:c22d Logitech, Inc. G510 Gaming Keyboard
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc22d G510 Gaming Keyboard
  bcdDevice            1.65
  iManufacturer           1 Logitech
  iProduct                2 G510 Gaming Keyboard
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0042
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     166
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               4
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

so you can see that the keyboard has 1 configuration and 2 interfaces. The first interface has 1 endpoint, and the second has 2 endpoints.
I need to write some bytes to the second endpoint of the second interface (this is the way to write on the little LCD display present on the keyboard), and theoretically I know how to do that using pyusb (usb.core.find, get interface, detach from kernel, claim etc.), but there's a big problem: **this is my main and only keyboard**, so I can't detach the kernel driver, otherwise I lose access to the keyboard and the only way to get back to being able to type is to physically unplug and plug back the keyboard!

```
import usb
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x046d, idProduct=0xc22d)
i = dev[0].interfaces()[1]
e=i.endpoints()[1]
print(e)
      ENDPOINT 0x3: Interrupt OUT ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x4
n=e.write('a')    # Just for test
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 16] Resource busy
```

And if I insert

```
dev.detach_kernel_driver(i.bInterfaceNumber)
```

I lose the use of the keyboard

The kernel driver manage the normal keyboard and the macro/memory/display keys too (G1, G2 ... G18, M1 .. MR and the 5 black keys under the display) but not the display.

**So how can I get access to that endpoint leaving all the rest of the keyboard handling to the linux kernel?**
Thanks for any help